# Update não é realizado no Banco de Dados utilizando o Sequelize e NodeJS

Tags: javascript, banco-de-dados, node.js, sequelize-js

Tenho a seguinte rota que é responsável por receber os dados vindo de um formulário e fazer um update dos dados que se encontram no meu banco de Dados

```
router.post('/articles/update', (req, res) => {
    let id = req.body.id; 
    let title = req.body.title;
    let body = req.body.body;
    let category = req.body.category;

    Article.update({title: title, body: body, categoryId: category, slug: slugify(title)}, {
        where: {
            id: id,
        }
    }).then(() => {
        res.redirect('/admin/articles');
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log('Error' + error)
    });
})
```

Quando a rota é executada, todas as ações são efetivadas inclusive sou redirecionado para a página do admin/articles (cai no Then uma vez que a função retornou sucesso) porém os dados não são alterados no banco de dados. Qual a razão?

Comment: No código postado não há erro algum, tanto é que é executado o **then()**, provavelmente o erro está em outro lugar.A não ser que os valores não estejam de acordo. Já deu um `log` nesses valores das variáveis aí pra ver, principalmente a variável **`id`**?

Comment: Pois é cara!! Fui lá e de fato é aí que está o problema, o id (req.body.id) está retornando vazio. Agora é descobrir a razão, uma vez que o name do formulário aonde envio o ID é exatamente esse que recebo na minha rota. Mas isso já salvou demais, obrigado cara! :D

Answer (score 1):

```
router.post('/articles/update', (req, res) => {
  const { id, title, body, category } = req.body || {}

  try {
    Article.update({ title, body, categoryId: category, slug: slugify(title) }, { where: { id } })
    res.redirect('/admin/articles')
  } catch (error) {
    console.log('Error:' + error)
  }
})
```

Talvez se você jogar dentro de um `try/catch` pode ser que te ajude a debugar melhor